# How do I find where the BTC are sent to from a blockchain.com address page?

Tags: transactions, wallet, tracking

I could see a wallet address receiving BTC easily on a blockchain.com

But it seems very hard to find out where he/she spend the BTC.

Does anyone know how to track that?

The screenshot below: the red box is the wallet address. It's always on the receiving end.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blockchain.com is an explorer, and like most explorers, it will show any transactions that spend from that address as well. If there are no such transactions, then the received coins have not been spent yet.

Note that even if such transactions are visible, it is not guaranteed that you will be able to identify where the coins were sent. Addresses are pseudonymous, and it is not always possible to identify the owner of the addresses the coins are sent to.

Comment: If someone scams me, and I pay some BTC to that person @ some wallet address, am I able to trace where he/she spends the BTC?

Comment: Not without the assistance of law enforcement or other services who have access to various coin tracking tools. In exceptional cases, you could figure it out yourself, but that's unlikely to be the case without significant contextual experience in the space

Comment: So if I have a wallet address, I can easily see who's funding the address, but I can't easily see where the wallet owner spent the coins, right?

Comment: You can see the address the coins were spent to, but you cannot easily determine who owns that address

Comment: This is a bit weird. Why blockchain.com can easily see how people fund an address, not how people send coins. I mean, technically...

Comment: Again - if the coins have been sent out, blockchain.com will show the outgoing transaction, including the address they were sent to. HOWEVER, even after you know the address they were sent to, you will likely not be able to identify the owner without help from coin tracking services.

Comment: Actually I don't need to identify anyone with an address. I just want to know, how do I see where the money is sent to. It's just like in your bank account you can see who sends you money and who your money sent to. But on blockchain.com I can only see one direction: who sends the money to the wallet, not who the wallet sent to.

Comment: The outgoing transactions are only visible if the coins have been spent. If there are no outgoing transactions, they're still in that wallet. You can check back later to see if they have been spent.